# Adaptative interface with Open GL and machine learning in C#

Tags: c#, machine-learning, opengl

For my Semester project I have to go for any Adaptative Interface Design.
My language is C# and I have to Use OpenTK (wrapper for OpenGL).

I have an idea that I should show two points and some obstacles and my subject (user) would drag an object from one place to the final place avoiding the Obstacles. Also (s)he can place obstacles randomly.

My software should be able to learn some paths by doing test runs and then after learning it should be able to predict the shortest path.

I do not know how stupid this idea sounds but it is just an idea. I need help regarding 
any ideas for adaptative interface possible small projects or if my idea is ok then please can you tell me what should be used to implement it? I mean that along with OpenGl for the Graphics what can I use for machine learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is rather old, but I found it interesting so I hope it still helps.

I particularly don't see the need to use machine learning as a tool for this question.

For the shortest path if you assume the drawing surface is discrete, you can see it as a grid. Therefore you find yourself actually in a maze routing problem. The most common solution for this is the Lee Algorithm. Take a look at [this lesson](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/~haizhou/357/lec6.pdf) for more information.

For graphics, unless you really want to do this I'd avoid OpenGL and I'd go for a slighter higher level API such Qt's QGraphicsScene.

I hope this helps :)